# Content Security Policy error with unstyled sitemap.xml in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy, inline-styles, sitemap.xml

My current Chrome Browser version (as of today, see version number below) gives me this error message *twice* (locations: `VM523:29` and `sitemap.xml:1`) in the developer console, when I request my `sitemap.xml` from [here](https://pureandroid.com/sitemap.xml):

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following  
Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'".  
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash  
('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='),  
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

The `sitemap.xml` has no styles (it's generated by Zola, a static site generator written in Rust), Firefox `119.0 (64-bit)` does not report any problem (but it says: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.`). Even the Google's CSP [evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com) cannot find any problems.

Is this a problem with Google's Chrome Browser, or it there anything I can do to fix the problem?

Chrome version: Version 118.0.5993.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu Linux Desktop 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Hm, just found out that even `https://content-security-policy.com/sitemap.xml` has this problem with my version of Chrome. Yes, it's not an official site, but claims to know something about the topic.

Comment: Without `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'`, Chrome is not rendering my `sitemap.xml` as usual, but displays it as something like plain text. Since it seems to be a decision by Chrome to load some other resources to format it, but does so probably in the context of the page, these resources are not compatible with my Content Security Policy, and ... boom. It's just a guess, but sounds plausible. If so, this might be a Chrome bug.

Comment: As a workaround, I have added `img-src 'self' data: http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` and `style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-p08VBe6m5i8+qtXWjnH/AN3klt1l4uoOLsjNn8BjdQo='` to my CSP. It fixes the problem with `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'`, but ... I'm not happy.
Mozilla Observatory now says `Content Security Policy (CSP) implemented, but secure site allows images or media to be loaded over HTTP`. Minus 10 points. Hm. But better than before.